# GPS Service stops after push power button

Tags: android, android-service, android-gps, android-powermanager

I'm starting a GPS location service on several devices, the service works correctly in devices with Android Version <= 7 even when the power button is pressed and in the lockscreen status, but I tried in a Nokia 3 with Android 8.0.0 and the service stops after push the power button but it doesn't stop when the device locks by itself after some time. When I push the power button and unlock the device the service starts to send the GPS data again. This is my code:

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {
private static final String TAG = GPS_Service.class.getName();
private static final int minTimeSecondsSamplingRate = AppConfig.GPS_MIN_TIME;
private static final int minDistMetersSamplingRate = AppConfig.GPS_MIN_DISTANCE;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");
            Intent intentSendToMainActivity = new Intent(AppConfig.C_STR_INTENT_FILTER_LOCATION_CHANGED);
            intentSendToMainActivity.putExtra(AppConfig.C_STR_LATITUDE, location.getLatitude());
            intentSendToMainActivity.putExtra(AppConfig.C_STR_LONGITUDE, location.getLongitude());
            sendBroadcast(intentSendToMainActivity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeSecondsSamplingRate, minDistMetersSamplingRate, locationListener);
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting Location Service");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't Start Location Service");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}
```

}

I've tried dissabling the battery optimization for my application but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

stop/start location update if no location is received in 2 minutes 
also create a service an make it foreground and put location updates methods inside it

all the best